# Dynamic proxy child object = null does not work

Tags: c#

I'm re-asking this from a question a couple of days ago now I've whittled the problem down.

Two simple objects:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I find a `Parent` object using a `DbContext` method e.g.

```
Parent parentToUpdate = _context.Parent.Find(1);
```

This object comes equipped with a populated child already, say with Id 22, generated as a `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxy`

I then have a new child object which becomes a null because it wasn't found in the database, using the same DbContext:

```
Child newChild = _context.Child.Find(999); // returns null
```

I then try to overwrite the `parentToUpdate` object's child with the `newChild` object:

```
parentToUpdate.Child = newChild;
```

I expect `.Child` to become null - This doesn't work *unless I step through the code* - The `parentToUpdate.Child` doesn't become null!

**WHY?** and **How can I nullify my `parentToUpdate.Child` object?** before I do `_context.SaveChanges()`

Comment: Could it be that the `Find(999)` is not called until you try accessing any property of `newChild` because of lazy loading?

Comment: I figured it might have something to do with lazy loading because I'm using `virtual` property on my object - how can I enforce it? It's weird that debugging step by step works perfectly each time but not when running normally.

Comment: I've stopped using EF some time ago, can you please try printing `newChild` before assigning it to `parentToUpdate.Child`?

Comment: I tried `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newChild);` and `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newChild.Id.ToString());` and it has no effect. I might have to just split it up into different context access operations...

Comment: Or I wonder can I just saveChanges() and then carry on within the same `using _context` block then saveChanges() again :/ Not sure that's even possible in the logic chain I have, worth a shot.

Comment: It was lazy loading, but actually on the parent object's child. I had to `include` it and instead of using `Find` just use `Where Id == x`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to the breadcrumb of lazy loading I ended up circling back on `Include` which I'd glossed over earlier looking for a solution.

It's as simple as changing the `Find` in context statement from

```
Parent parentToUpdate = _context.Parent.Find(1);
```

To

```
Parent parentToUpdate = _context.Parent.Include(x => x.Child).Where(x => x.Id == 1);
```